# Can not debug a github project locally , but able to install it and run it as program, error due to import issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I know how to import and I have developed some python project , I was trying to contribute to [sandman2](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman2) , when I cloned and tried to run it it gave me import error found that it is importing from sandman2 package itself,so when I run the `"__main__"` it tries to import module from sandman2 itself which does not exists because its not been installed.

I am new to opensource and I really want to edit/run this project locally , below is the error and file structure screenshot.

[image]

Comment: be sure to issue import statements in the correct working directory. In your case navigate up one directory and import from there.

Comment: its not working , still the same error

Comment: Then try running `python -m sandman2`